# logical operator error matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I'm writing a function in an electrical engineering class as a part of a lab where we're to build an oscilloscope. This particular function is our software "trigger circuit." This function is just supposed to register as 1 if it meets certain conditions. The exact wording is:

"Write a MATLAB function called triggering_circuit that has the input parameters: past_sample, current_sample, trigger_level, and trigger_slope. The function is to return a value of 1 if trigger_level is between past_sample and current_sample and the difference between the current sample and the past sample (i.e., current_sample - past_sample) has the same sign as trigger_slope."

We feel as if we've written the function properly, but when we try to call it in our function, we get the error:

"Error in triggering_circuit (line 4)
if trigger_level >= past_sample && trigger_level <= current_sample"

It's not giving any other errors, except that the function isn't assigning anything to the output variable m. I imagine, that's because the function won't finish running.

Now, I've looked online and I don't understand how we could be using the logical operator wrong. I would really appreciate any help.

The function is as follows:

```
function [ m ] = triggering_circuit( past_sample, current_sample, trigger_level, trigger_slope )

if trigger_level >= past_sample && trigger_level <= current_sample
    a = current_sample - past_sample;
    if a < 0 && trigger_slope < 0
        m = 1;
    elseif a > 0 && trigger_slope > 0
            m = 1;
    else
        m = 0;
    end
end
end
```

Comment: Verify your inputs are as expected, and I'd imagine you should set `m=0` if you don't enter the main `if`-statement. You are also assuming that `current_sample` is bigger than `past_sample`.

Comment: Ok, so I added the m = 0, but that still doesn't fix the problem. Apparently my past_sample and current_sample were vectors, which I didn't originally realize. At that point I change the && to an & right? Is there anything else I have to change?

Comment: How can a vector be larger than an other vector? The description does not make sense for input vectors. Please provide some example input and describe the expected output.

Comment: Well it's difficult then, because then if some elements of one vector will be less than or equal to corresponding elements of the other vector, but other elements might not be. Then is your condition true or false? And then what do you do with those vectors to calculate `m`?

Comment: I apologize. Our main function is very large, and I misunderstood what was going on. past_sample and current_sample are just being changed in a for loop, they aren't actually vectors.
An example of past_sample and current_sample:
past_sample =

    0.9884


current_sample =

    1.0130
One last point, m is being set as 1 depending on the conditions. It's more of an indicator than anything else.
sorry for the edits.

Comment: If they are just numbers then nothing should go wrong assuming trigger level is also a number. Go to debug mode, set breakpoints in `if` and `elseif` part and then see if it enters there at all.

Comment: Trigger level and trigger slope are both numbers = 1

Comment: @Auxilio so did you place breakpoints in `if` and `elseif` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function [ m ] = triggering_circuit(past_sample, current_sample, trigger_level,  trigger_slope )
    if trigger_level >= past_sample && trigger_level <= current_sample
        a = current_sample - past_sample;
        if a < 0 && trigger_slope < 0
            m = 1;
        elseif a > 0 && trigger_slope > 0
            m = 1;
        else
            m = 0;
        end
    else
        m = 0; %# This is where you would set m = 0
    end
end
```

I am not sure if you have already figured it out, but you must return something for the output argument that is declared with the function (m in this case) and in the current setup, there is a case where nothing can be returned.

So a function call in your code such as this:

m = triggering_circuit(0.9884, 1.0130, 1, 1)
Returns m = 1 when you call it.

Also here are the references for the logical operands:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorselementwise.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html